# Odoo 9: Add custom field to HR Contract using module

Tags: odoo-9

I'm new to Odoo. All I need is to add a simple custom field (i.e. Allowance) to HR Contract. I have followed the tutorial given in https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/add-custom-fields-to-sales-order-45074 but it for sales order. I tried to apply the concept to HR Contract but there is no success. I keep receive errors when I tried to install.

See below for the current code.

**__openerp__.py**

```
{
    'name': "hr_contract_customfield",

    'summary': """
        Add custom field to HR Contract""",

    'description': """
        Add custom field to HR Contract
    """,

    'author': "Author",
    'website': "http://www.companyname.com",

    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

     'depends': ['base','hr'],

     'data': [
         'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],

    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

**models.py**

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class hr_contract_customfield(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.contract'
    x_allowance_field = fields.Float('Allowance')
```

**templates.xml**

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="my_view_hr_contract_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">my.view.hr.contract.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_contract.hr_contract_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='wage']" position="after">
                    <field name="x_allowance_field"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Any advice?

**Error appeared when tried to install**

```
Error details:
Field `x_allowance_field` does not exist

Error context:
View `my.view.hr.contract.form.inherit`
[view_id: 882, xml_id: n/a, model: hr.contract, parent_id: 584]
None" while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/custom/hr_contract_customfield/views/templates.xml:3, near
<record id="my_view_hr_contract_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">my.view.hr.contract.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_contract.hr_contract_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='wage']" position="after">
                        <field name="x_allowance_field"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Does it give any usable error? From the Original Module definition of [hr.contract](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/hr_contract/__openerp__.py) I'd assume dependencies should be `hr_contract` (in difference to the example where sales.order is part of the sales module), not sure about `base` but it should not harm you. Also `demo/demo.xml` may be removed. Don't see anything else but I did mostly OpenERP 7/8.

Comment: I have changed to hr_contract and removed demo/demo.xml. But I'm still getting the same error. Error details are in the post.

Comment: Are you having a `__init__.py` that imports your model?

Comment: Yes. the `__init__.py` was created during the scoffold. There are two lines of code only `from . import controllers
from . import models`

Comment: Seems okay so far and I don't see any differences to [the Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-inheritance) but it seems the hr.contract model is not extended. If nothing goes you could delete the bytecode files like *.pyc from your module and restart Odoo. See if it actually finds and loads it. OpenERP 7/8 had often trouble with new/changing modules and gave wrong errors until we restarted the Server, thought that was mostly with the XML changes.

Comment: I removed all the *.pyc files and restarted the server. The error of `Field x_allowance_field does not exist` still presists when I tried to install the module.

Comment: I did another test by removing `<field name="x_allowance_field"/>` code from templates.xml and I managed to installed the module. Then I insert the code back and upgrade the module. After that the *.pyc files are created. With these steps done, I managed to add the custom field. But still it will be troublesome whenever I want to install in new server.

Comment: This is weird indeed. Earlier OpenERP had init_xml and update_xml data fields in `__openerp__.py` to control how it's applied. Now you can only switch between "install and upgrade" or "install" like [this Odoo Forum Post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/difference-between-init-xml-updata-xml-data-fields-26569) but maybe this is your Problem, needing it to be _install only_ due to having a different view id. Anyway, congratulations for finding a workaround for now and good luck.